# Angular CLI - ng serve - high cpu usage from node process

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, node-gyp, fsevents

I am struggling with an issue where on running any angular app locally the node process linked to `ng serve` is using well over 100% of my CPU core's.

My current environment is:

Angular CLI: 7.3.10
Node: 11.15.0
OS: darwin x64 (Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.4)
Angular: 7.2.16

I have come across numerous posts and issues about this where the common solutions appear to be to install `fsevents` for Mac OS issues.

Things I have tried:

- Installing XCode Command Line Tools for `node-gyp` to rebuild `fsevents` after its installed
- Install the latest version of `fsevents` (2.1.3) as an older version is specified as an optional dependency with angular-cli (1.2.13)
- Using a different node version, tried 12.13.0 and deleting node_modules and doing a clean install. Also tried latest fevents version again

  - Incase its relevant I use `nvm` also
- Tried `npm rebuild`
- Upgrading one of my apps from Angular 7 to 9, still same behaviour after clean install of dependencies, ensuring fsevents is installed and trying latest version too

No matter what I try, I keep observing high cpu usage, I have seen it creep up too 300-400% at times.

This is really hampering my development and I am hoping someone may have some bright ideas I could try out.

Failing that, I am wondering if I should try uninstalling `node` completely, getting rid of `nvm` and starting from scratch.

Comment: I didn't realise poll was milliseconds, I had it on 5  -- it was also causing my cpu to spike - thanks for the update

Comment: If you find an answer yourself, [post it as an answer](/help/self-answer); don't edit it into your question

Answer (score 26):

In Angular development context; transpilation/compilation causes CPU spike. When this happens too frequent, your system is in trouble.

There are certain ways to relieve the pain a little;

- Turn off file change detection / live-reload / auto compilation entirely

`ng serve --live-reload false` or `ng serve --no-live-reload` etc. depending on your Angular CLI version

- Have a better change detection, react only when really needed

`npm install fsevents`

`npm rebuild fsevents`

`npm serve`

- Forget change detection, check changes based on a time interval

`ng serve --poll [ms]`

CPU management is tricky, there can be many reasons for this problem. These are only a few possibilities closely related to Angular development. I hope this answer provides some options to try to the ones having the same trouble.

Comment: Working at an Angular 9 project: Installing fsevents calmed down the node process which otherwise was running constantly at ~60% CPU. Now I rarely see it in the Activity Monitor. If using Node 14+ you may install fsevents@2.

Comment: --poll did it for me

Comment: If you're on Apple Silicon, the current version of fsevents (2.2.1) doesn't work properly. See: https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/349 for a workaround.

Comment: Why does `ng serve` use fsevents without telling to use fsevents? How can I tell to use chokidar?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have similar setup for you hot/live reloading on `Docker` such as `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 1`. The `poll` value is problematic, change it on something larger, for example `2000`, such that `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 2000`.

Now, you'll loose (almost) real-time hot/live reloading, but you'll save your CPU/battery and having 2 seconds delay before your app will refresh the changed code.

Answer (score 0):

it seems i managed to resolve the problem:
delete the /node_module and install again

in my case that helped
i found the advise here: 
https://gitmemory.com/issue/angular/angular-cli/14748/501608887

Answer (score 0):

If you use Yarn to install packages, its lockfile may have locked in an older version of `fsevents` which has known issues with `node-pre-gyp` on Apple Silicon.

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/2296

Simply deleting `yarn.lock`, and running `yarn` again, should attempt to install newer versions of the `fsevents` dependency, which does not have that issue.

This worked with Angular 11.

Answer (score 0):

Set a time interval for changes check

```
ng serve --poll 4000
```

e.g. [4000] is 4 seconds

it will helps with the CPU usage problem

Answer (score -1):

Setting the flag `--watch=false` is what reduced CPU usage of my angular process from 50% to 0%:

```sh
ng serve --configuration=dev --watch=false
```